# How to overwrite portions of a DriverKit OSData internal buffer?

Tags: macos, driverkit, macos-system-extension

The documentation of [`OSData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/osdata?language=objc) says that *"...You can add bytes to them and overwrite portions of the byte array."*. I can see a method to [append](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/osdata/3180877-appendbytes?language=objc) bytes, but I don't understand how I am able to overwrite a portion of the buffer.

Another option would be to use `IONewZero` to allocate a number of elements of the type I need. I my case I just need this for `int`s.

Example:

```
T* dataBuffer = IONewZero(T, SIZE);
```

And then deallocate with:

```
IOSafeDeleteNULL(dataBuffer_, T, SIZE);
```

What are the advantages of using an `OSData` object compared to the solution with `IONewZero` / `IOSafeDeleteNULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation might just be copy-pasted from the kernel variant of `OSData`. I've seen that in a bunch of places, especially USBDriverKit.

`OSData` is mostly useful for dealing with plist-like data structures (i.e. setting and getting properties on service objects) in conjunction with the other OSTypes: `OSArray`, `OSDictionary`, `OSNumber`, etc. It's also used for in-band (<= 4096 byte) "struct" arguments of user client external methods.

The only use I can see outside of those scenarios is when you absolutely have to reference-count a blob of data. But it's certainly not a particularly convenient or efficient container for data-in-progress. If you subsequently need to send the data to a device or map it to user space, `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor` is probably a better choice (and also reference counted) though it's even more heavyweight.